# filter title from shortcode

Tags: filters, shortcode

Just wondering how to filter to change the current page title from a shortcode,

Since shortocodes are rendering after $post.

any idea to archieve something like : `do_shortcode(['mytitle="newtitle"']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not to use **the_title** filter?

```
add_filter('the_title', 'the_title_filter');
function the_title_filter($title){
    $post = get_post(get_the_id());
    //enter code here
    return $title;
}
```

as for shortcode - its imposible. in logical way - imposible.

Comment: can you explain better? why is impossible?

Comment: It's impossible because the title has already been generated before shortcodes are parsed.

Comment: You could allow shortcodes for the title (like for anything else) too. Not that it would make much sense.